# Gitlab Ci: execute a stage for any branch except A or B

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I want to run the stage `publish_snapshot_rpm` for any branch except `master` or `release`. The pipeline runs successfully but the stage `publish_snapshot_rpm` is not executed. What am I missing? The part of my `gitlab-ci` file:

```
.publish:
  stage: publish
  tags:
    - dev
  dependencies:
    - build

publish_snapshot_rpm:
  extends: .publish
  only:
#    for any branch except master or release
    - (?!(master|release)\b)\b\w+
  script:
    - some script here
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily achieve this by using the power of the [`rules`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules) keyword.

```
rules:
  - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == master
    when: never
  - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ /^release/
    when: never
  - when: on_success
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way with the use of `except`:

```
.publish:
  stage: publish
  tags:
    - dev
  dependencies:
    - build

publish_snapshot_rpm:
  extends: .publish
  except:
        - master
        - release
  script:
    - some script here
```

Comment: "only and except are not being actively developed. rules is the preferred keyword to control when to add jobs to pipelines."